# Google Maps v3 too close and height is incorrect on jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap

Tags: android, css, google-maps, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to add Google maps v3 with Geolocation into my jQuery Mobile / PhoneGap Android app but I've some problems:

1. It locates my position correct, but it's (the radius?) too close. I've changed the value of the radius at my code, but nothing happens. You can see the problem here: http://s7.directupload.net/images/131214/nbc3wudy.png
2. The second problem concers the height. You can see that at the screenshot too. The maps is too high for the screen, but I don't know how to change it.
3. And the last problem is this error: /android_asset/www/js/jquery.ui.map.js: Line 46 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined

Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="GPS">

    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">LeftPanel</a>
        <h1></h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="map-content">
        <div id="map-container"></div>  
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#GPS').on("pagecreate", function() {     
        var positionOutput = function(position){
            var longpos = position.coords.longitude;
            var latpos = position.coords.latitude;    
            $('#map-container').height($(window).height());                 

            $('#map-container').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(position, status) {
                if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                    var clientPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    $('#map-container').gmap('addMarker', {'position': clientPosition, 'bounds': true});
                    $('#map-container').gmap('addShape', 'Circle', { 
                        'strokeWeight': 0, 
                        'fillColor': "#008595", 
                        'fillOpacity': 0.25, 
                        'center': clientPosition, 
                        'radius': 15, 
                        'clickable': false 
                    });
                }
            });     

        };

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionOutput);
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#map-content {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: problem #2 `var page = $("[data-role=page]").height();
        var header = $("[data-role=header]").outerHeight();
        var footer = $("[data-role=footer]").outerHeight();
        var content = page - (header + footer);
        $("#map-container").height(content);` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pMv7z/

Comment: @Omar. Better then before, but not perfect. Here is the new screenshot: http://s7.directupload.net/images/131214/5c3jmojc.png

Comment: try `$("[data-role=header]").height();` then.

Comment: Unfortunately, no change

Comment: Any joy with this? I have the 'Line 46 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined' error too.

Comment: For issue #1 it looks like you're zoomed in too far because your bounds are set to one point. Try setting a maximum zoom level, or define your map's bounds by more than one point.